# characterize certain type of matrices

Tags: reference-request, linear-algebra, matrices

I am trying to characterize matrices with a certain property :
Define $U$ as an $n \times n$ matrix (over C or R; you can also assume
that it is unitary or orthogonal if it helps). Now take $n$
unknowns and transform by $U$ : $y=Ux$; I want the product
$y_1 y_2 \cdots y_n = \sum c_i x_i^n$; so basically I don't
want any "cross terms". In the case of $n=2$ this would put
a restriction on $U=((a,b),(c,d))$ : $ad+bc=0$; and $y_1y_2$ would be $c_1x_1^2+c_2x_2^2$; My question
is : are such matrices known in the literature by some name?
and can they be characterized in any nice way? (minimal number
of parameters,...)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm guessing that these don't have a name, as they are fairly degenerate matrices.

If more than two of the $c_i$ are nonzero, then no matrices satisfy these criteria. This follows since the Fermat curve
$$X^n + Y^n = Z^n$$
is irreducible and a decomposition as you describe would make it a union of lines.

If two of the $c_i$ are nonzero, then all such matrices of this form have two columns $j, j'$ with nonzero entries and have $M_{ij}/M_{ij'}$ going through all $n^{th}$ roots of some nonzero complex number.

If one $c_i$ is nonzero, then only one column has nonzero entries, and all its entries are nonzero.

If all the $c_i$ are zero, then some row of $M$ is zero.

Comment: Thanks for the response. The motivation for the question came from a totally
different angle (optics); I didn't think of the problem in terms of factoring.
If I follow your answer correctly this would imply that adding the requirement
that the matrix is invertable would mean that only the case $n=2$ has solutions.
This negative result would have value on its own. Do you have a good reference for
the irreducibality of the fermat curve? also the fermat curve is in only 3 variables,
can I assume that the general $\sum_1^n x_i^n$ is also irreducible?